{rast] cannot open this file
I am working with the terra package to read a raster file.
narr <- rast(paste0(
  "/   YOUR FILE PATH   /narr_air2m_",
  year,
  ".nc"
))

When I run this code, I encounter the following error:

Error: [rast] cannot open this file as a SpatRaster: H:/2024_Emory_SPH/Geospatial Project/Data/narr_air2m_2020.nc
In addition: Warning message:
H:/2024_Emory_SPH/Geospatial Project/Data/narr_air2m_2020.nc' not recognized as a supported file format. (GDAL error 4)

I have tried various methods to resolve the issue, but I am unable to figure out what to do.
update.Packages("terra")
install.packages("ncdf4")
library(ncdf4)

nc_data <- nc_open("H:/2024_Emory_SPH/Geospatial Project/Data/narr_air2m_2020.nc")
print(nc_data)

Working with Raster:
year <- "2021"

Specify the URL where data is stored based on year variable of interest:
url_narr <- paste0(
  "https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov//Datasets/NARR/Dailies/monolevel/air.2m.",
  year,
  ".nc"
) 

Specify where to save downloaded data:
destination_narr <- paste0(
  "/   YOUR FILE PATH   /narr_air2m_",
  year,
  ".nc"
)

download the data:
download.file(
url_narr,
destination_narr
)
narr <- rast(paste0(
"/   YOUR FILE PATH   /narr_air2m_",
  year,
  ".nc"
))


Welcome to SO. Thanks for showing some code. However, the formatting makes it difficult to read. I suspect that you can fix the formatting by removing "your text" and using proper placement of the " ` " symbol to highlight the code correctly. That's the symbol to the left of the 1 keys on an U.S. keyboard. I suspect the main problem in the code itself has to do with what the object "YOUR FILE PATH" contains. Refer here for help with formatting your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?r=Saves_AllUserSaves

Thank you for your comment. I have tried to edit the entire body of the message.

The file opens fine, is well formed and self-describing (a good .nc), when loaded from local forlder. I think if you curl::curl_download(url = 'https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov//Datasets/NARR/Dailies/monolevel/air.2m.2020.nc', destfile = 'air.2m.2020.nc'), then <- rast('air.2m.2020.nc') all will be fine. And then play around with paste ;solve one problem at a time.

When using download.file() with binary files in Windows , it must be called with mode = "wb" ,  some more common file extensions trigger mode update within the function, but for .nc  you definetly need to set it yourself. Or better yet, switch to curl::curl_download() as Chris suggested.

Thank you for your help. It was wonderful!
